# Auto login/Multipass login using lightspeed,zapier, auth0

Tags: auth0, zapier, lightspeed

It is possible to have a multipass login using auth0, zapier or ligthspeed from my own app to an online e-commerce platform like using shopify?Or it exists a cheaper solution?

Comment: Do you mean MFA?

Comment: I don't know what is MPA

Comment: https://auth0.com/learn/get-started-with-mfa/